# How to copy dates form one workbook to another using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

**Some background:**
Excel stores dates as serial numbers, with [1] being January 1 1990 and last month end (9/30/2021) being [43007]. However, when copying a date like 2021-09-30 into a new workbook, the date looks like [44469].

**The problem:** When copying dates from one workbook to another using vba, the dates are converted into a serial number that represents a date in the future. I'm wondering how to copy dates in a way that either won't convert them into serial numbers or to copy dates in a way that pastes the proper serial number.

**The copy data code I'm using:**

```
    '----Number of Rows & Cols for workbook with the data I want
    Dim wbRowCount As Integer
    Dim wbColCount As Integer

    wbRowCount = wb.worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    wbColCount = wb.worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

    '----Number of rows & cols for workbook with vba
    Dim startIndex As Integer
    Dim numRows As Integer
    Dim numCols As Integer

    startIndex = 0

    For numRows = 1 to wbRowCount
        For numCols = 1 to wbColCount
           Cells(numRows + startIndex, numcols) = wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(numRows, numCols)
        Next numCols
    Next numRows

    startIndex = numRows + 1
    numRows = 0
```

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69491218/16578424 - I assume that the source workbook has a different setting than the target workbook for _Use 1904 data system_. Use `wb.Date1904` to check the setting

Comment: Ty ty. This worked.